# Redux saga cancels previous while getting consecutive request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

In saga i create a generator that i am calling consecutively. when second call is made and the first call is in flight then first action get cancelled and i m getting only data from the second request 
here is my code
Initial state in reducer

```
export const initialState = {
sectionData:
{
    featuredData: false,
    popularData: false,
}}
```

featuredData and popularData get updated as per result from api call in saga

this is my saga code

```
function* getSectionData(){ yield takeLatest(LOAD_SECTION_DATA, fetchSectionData) }

function* fetchSectionData(action){
try
{
    var requestURL = `http://localhost:3001/v1/fetchData?page=` + action.section_name;
    console.log('Request Url', requestURL)
    const response = yield call(getRequest, requestURL);
    var result = {}
    if (action.section_name)
    {
        let sectionName = [action.section_name] + 'Data'
        result[sectionName] = response.data
    }
    console.log('Request result', result)
    yield put(sectionDataLoaded(result));
}
catch (err)
{
    yield put(sectionDataLoadingError(err));
}}

export default function* HomePageSaga(){ yield all([getSectionData()]); }
```

i am calling 
fetchSectionData('featured')
fetchSectionData('popular') consecutively
the result i am getting is

```
sectionData{
featuredData: false,
popularData: [{
    name: 'popular'
}]}
```

instead of

```
sectionData{
featuredData: [
{
    name: 'featured'
}],
popularData: [
{
    name: 'popular'
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly how takeLatest should work. If a request has been started and then another is made, the first request is cancelled. I think you want to use takeEvery instead. See https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/ for the functionality of takeEvery.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args)

In your case, **make sure to use [takeEvery](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeeverypattern-saga-args)**

Also [read](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1722)